# Saving localNotifications with UILocalNotifications and NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, save, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification, nscoding

I want to save all my scheduled `localNotifications` before app goes to background.

I get all the `localNotification` from `UIApplication`, and I try to save like:

```
NSArray *allNot =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *not = [allNot objectAtIndex:0];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:not forKey:@"notifications"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Now the problem occurs.

> Attempt to insert non-property value of class 'UIConcreteLocalNotification'.

When I get the local notifications from my `[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` I obtain an array of `UIConcreteLocalNotification`. The problem is that the `UILocalNotification` is conform to `NSCoding` but this object `UIConcreteLocalNotification` is not.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you cast the object retrieved using *objectAtIndex:* method?

```
UILocalNotification *not = (UILocalNotification *) [allNot objectAtIndex:0];
```